# hey everyone i'm struggling to make an oauth with reddit api but i keep getting errors i'm using react native

Tags: android, react-native

Running "AwesomeProject" with {"rootTag":41}
LOG  https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=xA9ONvdOMlRl20GfqLJ_ow&response_type=code&state=random_string&redirect_uri=myawesomeapp://oath&duration=temporary&scope=identity
WARN  Can't open url: myawesomeapp://oath?state=random_string&code=NML55ykPvQjochsxqE2ZeV1yXoSM_Q#_
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
ReferenceError: Property 'Buffer' doesn't exist
ReferenceError: Property 'Buffer' doesn't exist